# Starting HTTPS in Express 4.x

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to start the server in HTTPS using Express 4.x. I tried

```
  var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
  var app = express(credentials);
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Where does this comes from?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could easily just do something like this:

```
var app = express(),
    credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate},
    server = https.createServer(credentials, app);
server.listen(8443);
```

Comment: One thing I've found useful to debug express is `DEBUG=express:* node app.js`.  This turns on the internal debug log for express.

Comment: where to put it ?